# How do I access HTML elements that are rendered in JavaScript using XPath?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

How do I get a `<td>` with a specific class name using XPath and Nokogiri? Tables are nested and some of them don't have IDs or classes, so I can't nest stuff like this:

```
//table/tbody/tr/td
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.goalzz.com/default.aspx?c=8358"))
  doc.xpath('//td[@class="m_g"]').each do |node|
  pp node.to_s
end
```

Any ideas? There are few `<td>`s with that class name and I want to get all of them.

Comment: The example web page is built dynamically using javascript. Nokogiri would not be a good candidate to for this page. If you wanted to force this page you could load the script value of 'var comp_pointsbox' into a Nokogiri object. Standard Nokogiri::HTML(open) will not work as intended due the JS.

Comment: Ok. I thought the page is ready for scraping by Nokogiri regardless of how it was generated.

Comment: I see what you mean now. I don't think messing with the JS object is worth it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using gem "capybara-webkit" is a viable way of manipulating this website in full javascript rendered view.

Here is a scratch example of what a capybara-webkit script might look like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "rubygems"
require "pp"
require "bundler/setup"
require "capybara"
require "capybara/dsl"
require "capybara-webkit"

Capybara.run_server = false
Capybara.current_driver = :webkit
Capybara.app_host = "http://www.goalzz.com/"

module Test
  class Goalzz
    include Capybara::DSL

    def get_results
      visit('/default.aspx?c=8358')
      all(:xpath, '//td[@class="m_g"]').each { |node| pp node.to_s }

    end
  end
end

spider = Test::Goalzz.new
spider.get_results
```

What is required to find the example xpath in this case (due to the page being created dynamically), is a fully functional javascript webdriving engine.

Comment: Wow, this looks like a nice solution. I am installing qt now (its taking some time). I will get back at you when thats done.

Comment: Fantastic answer @shadowbq. Works like a sharm. :)

Comment: Only viable way? You're forgetting about watir, celerity, and a few others.

Comment: Yes Watir-WebDriver would work fine. Celerity is Jruby only from my understanding. I suppose selenium would work as well. Its a matter of how complicated/robust you want your headless scraping to be.

Comment: There is an interesting article on the three side-by-side using benchmark. [A tale of three ruby automated testing APIs](http://watirmelon.com/2011/12/03/a-tale-of-three-ruby-automated-testing-apis-redux/). Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Are the class attributes on these `td`s exactly "m_g", or do they have more than one class on a single `td`?  If it's the latter, this XPath might work:

```
//td[contains(@class, "m_g")]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The class attributes are exactly what I specified. Your suggestion yields nothing, just like mine.

Comment: I just realized that I can actually go to that URL and see the page.  I also, like shadowbq, discovered that the page is generated dynamically, and I couldn't find the value `m_g` even in the JavaScript.

Comment: Yep, same with me. I somehow trusted the page is generated statically. My bad.